# Capybara select options

Tags: ruby, drop-down-menu, web-scraping, phantomjs, capybara

im trying to do an scraper using Capybara and PhantomJS, I have to look for some items, that appear when you interact with 3 dropdown menus, the first dropdown gives you the options for the second one and the second one gives you the options for the third one, so, this is my question, I'm already listing the options on the first dropdown, but when I click on the first element the loop stops, and didn't execute the other options on the dropdown menu.

This is my code.

```
find(:xpath, "//a[contains(@id, 'filterBrand-button')]").click
all(:xpath , "//*[contains(@id, 'filterBrand')]")[1].all('*').each do|option|
  if option.text != '-- Select --'
    puts option.text        
    option.click
    sleep(2)        
    find(:xpath, "//a[contains(@id, 'filterModel-button')]").trigger('click')
    sleep(2)       
     all(:xpath , "//*[contains(@id, 'filterModel')]")[0].all('*').each do|option2|
       if option2.text != '-- Select --'
         puts option2.text
         option2.click 
         find(:xpath, "//a[contains(@id, 'filterVersion-button')]").trigger('click')
         sleep(4)        
         all(:xpath , "//*[contains(@id, 'filterVersion')]")[0].all('*').each do|option3|
           if option3.text != '-- Select --'
             option3.click
             puts option3.text
           end
         end
       end
     end  
  end
```

I'm using the sleep command to wait till the dropdown loads the options, but after `option.click` the code shows nothing on the output

Well the HTML code is this.

```
<form name="searchForm" id="searchForm" action="http://search_action" method="POST" name="searchform">                                                                                              
  <p>
  <label class="left" for="filterBrand"> Marca </label>
  <select style="font-size:73%;" name="filterBrand" id="filterBrand" class="combo">
  </select>
   </p>
   <p>
   <label class="left" for="filterModel"> Modello</label>
   <select  style="font-size:73%;" onchange="searchProduct();" name="filterModel" id="filterModel" class="combo">                                                             
   </select>
   </p>
   <p>
   <label class="left" for="filterVersion">Versione</label>
   <select style="font-size:73%;" onchange="searchProduct();" name="filterVersion" id="filterVersion" class="combo">
   </select>               
   </p>
```

As you can see, there are no options on the dropdown selects, this options are loaded after you click on it. The issue, as I wrote in the first question, is that capybara doesn't execute the click method in any option besides the first one on the first dropdown select; but if you comment the click method you could see the full option list printed.

So, what I could tell is that after the click method is called, the loop is interrupted or that is what I could observe, in several executions.

Comment: Since you are using Ruby binding I strongly suggest you to move to WATIR which is a wrapper for Ruby selenium binding where you don't have to wait for options loading by writing a static sleep statement as you have done, you could find internal timer over there, it will hit the option as soon as options are loaded.

Comment: @RAJ Capybara actually has the same waiting behavior as Watir so the sleeps shouldnt be required for it either -  Watir actually implemented this because Capybara had it first - http://watirtight.com/2016/10/13/wait-in-the-watir.html.

Comment: Also phantomjs is no longer being developed so you may want a different driver.

Answer (score 0):

You're problem here is that you're using `all` but not passing any indication of how many elements you're expecting it to return.  This means 0 elements is an acceptable number and since there are no options right after your first select (until an AJAX request returns, so the whole page isn't being fully replaced or you'll have obsolete elements, I assume?) `all` will just return an empty array. The easiest solution is to just tell `all` you expect a minimum number of elements to be returned

```
find(:xpath, ".//a[contains(@id, 'filterBrand-button')]").click
all(:xpath , ".//*[contains(@id, 'filterBrand')]")[1].all('*', minimum: 2).each do |option| # Assuming you'll see `-- Select --` and at least one other 
if option.text != '-- Select --'
  puts option.text        
  option.click
  find(:xpath, ".//a[contains(@id, 'filterModel-button')]").trigger('click')
  all(:xpath , ".//*[contains(@id, 'filterModel')]", minimum: 1)[0].all('*', minimum: 2).each do|option2|
     if option2.text != '-- Select --'
       puts option2.text
       option2.click 
       find(:xpath, ".//a[contains(@id, 'filterVersion-button')]").trigger('click') # Needing to use trigger here is a red flag
       all(:xpath , ".//*[contains(@id, 'filterVersion')]", minimum: 1)[0].all('*', minimum: 2).each do|option3|
         if option3.text != '-- Select --'
           option3.click
           puts option3.text
         end
       end
     end
   end  
 end
```

Note: Starting each XPath selector with `.//` because of https://github.com/teamcapybara/capybara#beware-the-xpath--trap. Also I'm sure there are selectors you could be using that would make this read much better and clean it up, but without an example of the actual HTML it's impossible to make suggestions for that. One cleanup suggestion that can be made without the HTML is to move the '-- Select --' checking into the Capybara query

```
find(:xpath, "//a[contains(@id, 'filterBrand-button')]").click
all(:xpath , "//*[contains(@id, 'filterBrand')]")[1].all('*', minimum: 1, text: /^((?!-- Select --).)*$/).each do |option|# Element with `-- Select --` won't be matched so now minimum: 1 
  puts option.text        
  option.click
  find(:xpath, "//a[contains(@id, 'filterModel-button')]").trigger('click')
  all(:xpath , "//*[contains(@id, 'filterModel')]", minimum: 1)[0].all('*', minimum: 1, text: /^((?!-- Select --).)*$/).each do|option2|
    puts option2.text
    option2.click 
    find(:xpath, "//a[contains(@id, 'filterVersion-button')]").trigger('click') # Needing to use trigger here is a red flag
    all(:xpath , "//*[contains(@id, 'filterVersion')]", minimum: 1)[0].all('*', minimum: 2, text: /^((?!-- Select --).)*$/).each do|option3|
      option3.click
      puts option3.text
    end  
  end
end
```

Update: Since you've added the HTML (and assuming the button ids are exact and don't really need `contains` this would be clearer written as

```
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 6 # This just needs to be longer (in seconds) than however long the selects take to get their new entries

find('a#filterBrand-button').click
find(:select, 'filterBranch').all(:option, text: /^((?!-- Select --).)*$/, minimum: 1).each do |option|
  puts option.text        
  option.select_option
  find('a#filterModel-button').click
  find(:select, 'filterModel').all(:option, text: /^((?!-- Select --).)*$/, minimum: 1).each do |option2|
    puts option2.text
    option2.select_option
    find('a#filterVersion-button').click
    find(:select, 'filterVersion').all(:option, text: /^((?!-- Select --).)*$/, minimum: 1).each do |option3|
      option3.select_option
      puts option3.text
    end  
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi Thomas, I have tried all those recommendations, but still, just can list the options on the DropDown Menu, use WATIR is not viable, because it will take more time than is expected. If I have any progress I'll post

Comment: @AndresTorres That doesn't make any sense.  If there were no other options then the code I provided would have at least raised errors with some explanation.  If it did actually raise errors then it sounds like your page is probably using JS that is not supported by PhantomJS (any ES6+).  If you're using Poltergeist enabling the `js_errors` option MIGHT show that - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization